# iOS - what resolution for graphics to look good on all devices?

Tags: ios, graphics, resolution, resolution-independence

I have an app and want to place a graphics in it. If i make a graphics in high resolution,for example 2048 x 1536 (iPad), is there a way to downscale it properly to other devices with lower res? My goal is to avoid making n versions of graphics for diferent devices (@2x, ipad, etc...), all of them beign basically the same image just downsized in Photoshop. I would prefer to make one very high resolution graphics and downscale in iOS automaticaly (preserving ratio).

Answer (score 1):

Don't do this. When you go into a memory constrained device you'll have a higher chance to crash! Eg. putting iPhone 6 Plus (@3x) graphics into the lowest iOS 8 compatible device the iPod Touch.

I recommend if you don't want to do multiple images, mind you this is really trivial to do... You can try an application like PaintCode, it will inflate your binary a little but its usually smaller than an image set.

Comment: Thx! Besides memory issues (which i think are not very likely to occur on current generation hardware, even iPod Touch), do you see any other disadvantages of downscaling programaticaly?

Comment: It may look bad, you have more control over prebaked @nx images. Loading times are increased unnecessarily, (deflating and rendering.) You do save on app store package size though, but with Paintcode you'll fix all of those problems but added coding overhead.